# 404 Pages everywhere - can’t access backend after migration

Tags: magento, migration, http-status-code-404

Our site was recently transferred.

We followed instructions from this tutorial: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/move_magento_to_another_directory

I thought everything worked spledidly… now I am getting 404’s across the board… nothing is showing up and I can’t access the backend.

Can anyone give me any pointers??

Comment: yes :) search before you post n00b level questions here, it has been answered at least 100 times :) check your base url setting, regenerate indexes, clear caches bla bla

Answer (score 5):

Obviously it is a url settings issue. As you can't access  the backend now, there's another way to recover your site. Find

> app->etc->local.xml

**DELETE/RENAME it.**

Now **reinstall** your **Magento**, using the **same database** obviously. Your settings and products will remain as earlier but with a fresh new url.